# Why does my JavaFX have this program flow problem?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans, fxml

Using JavaFX and FXML I'm trying to display a screen with some basic information, and then when an HTTP call returns, update that screen.  What happens instead is the screen is not displayed at all until the call returns.  Below is minimum case test of the problem, with a delay meant to simulate the HTTP call.

I'd expect the screen to be displayed, the first label updated, a ten second delay, and then the second label updated.  Instead, the screen isn't displayed until after the delay has finished, and that happens no matter where I put the delay.  I'm hoping I'm overlooking something simple instead of having to create multiple threads to do something so simple.  Below is enough code I think for anyone able to answer the problem.  I can include more code if needed.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    this.stage = stage;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("primary.fxml"));
    anchroot = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    // Show the scene containing the root layout.
    Scene scene = new Scene(anchroot);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    PrimaryController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setMainApp(this);
    stage.show();

    //change the first label
    controller.setLabel0();

    //timer to simulate IO
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //try to change the second label 10 sec later
    controller.setLabel1();

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `controller.setLabel0()` and `controller.setLabel1()`. Also a more serious issue is that you are performing IO operations on the main thread, and this may have something to do with your issue. Creating multiple threads can be easier than you think with the `Service` class provided by JavaFX

Comment: You must **never** block, or execute long-running work on, the _JavaFX Application Thread_. That thread is responsible for updating UI state, processing user-generated events, and scheduling render "pulses". If you monopolize or block the FX thread then it can't do any of those things and you end up with a non-responsive (i.e. frozen) UI. You need to move any blocking or long-running work to a background thread, then publish any result(s) back to the FX thread to update the UI—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Calling `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);` will make `JavaFX` thread to block for 10 seconds. In this case you will not be able to see any changes in the GUI thread until the sleep period is finished. In JavaFX, you can use a `Timeline` to make updates after a certain period:

```java
controller.setLabel0();
new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), event -> controller.setLabel1())).play();
```